# How to redirect output to multiple variables?

Tags: shell, sh

I have to write every line of the following shell output to a single variable:

```
/bin/grep abc /etc/passwd | /bin/cut -d : -f 1
```

in the end there should be one variable for every user. like:

```
$user1 = abc
$user2 = abca
$user3 = abcb
...
```

the script must run on sh so I can't use arrays. I was thinking about a for-loop like:

```
for (int i = 0; i <= linecountOfOutput; i++)
   user + i = line i
```

is this possible in shell? or is there a more simple way to get these users?

Comment: How are you going to use these variables? This smells like an XY problem.

Comment: I will run an other script as those users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see how are you going to use this, but you can use eval:

```
txt=$(grep sys /etc/passwd | cut -d: -f1)
cnt=$(echo "$txt" | wc -l)
ite=$(seq 1 "$cnt")
for i in $ite; do
        line=$(echo "$txt" | sed "${i}q;d")
        eval "user$i=\"${line}\""
done
echo $user1
echo $user2
echo $user3
echo $user4
```

Comment: Thank You. 
I will run an other script as those users and there is a typing mistake in line 2. The variable in the echo is $txt.

Comment: Right, good catch. If you will run other script as those users, why don't you iterate over users with `for user in $txt; do sudo -u $user command; done` ?

Comment: I maybe caused a XY Problem here. I'm very sorry for that. 
You are right. This makes much more sense.